# How does `tkinter. Spinbox()` behaviour depends on the type of value passed to its `textvariable`

Tags: python, tkinter

Been trying to pick up on Python (3.4) and this is my first posting on Stack Overflow.
I have questions regarding the behaviour of the `textvariable` option in the `tkinter.Spinbox()` widget constructor.

The following codes are working. It's a layout of 6 spinboxes, there are 3 pairs of spinboxes (each pair side by side). Each spinbox in a pair are suppose to be independent of each other, i.e. when one changes, it's not suppose to affect the other.

Pair A receives their `textvariable` parameter as type `StringVar()` (e.g. `var = StringVar()`)

Pair B receives their `textvariable` parameter as string declared between quotes (e.g. `var = '0'`)

Pair C receives their `textvariable` parameter as type `integer` (e.g. `var = 0`)

Note: I'd like to post a screen capture of the resulting window but the page said "You need at least 10 reputation to post images"... of which I apparently do not have at the moment...

I'd just like to understand what is the reason behind why the members of Pair C seems to be "non-independent" of each other? -> Change one, and the other follows the with the same changes made.

How is the intepretation for the `textvariable` parameter in the `tkinter.Spinbox()` different for different types of value assigned?

Here are my codes:

```
from tkinter import *

class spinModuleStrA():
    ''' spinModuleNum() - Spinbox taking textvariable as <StringVar() value> '''
    def __init__(self, master, moduleName):
        self.root = master
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.root.grid()
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set('r')

        self.label1 = Label(self.root, text=self.moduleName, bg=self.root["bg"])
        self.label1.pack(expand = True)

        self.spinBox1 = Spinbox(self.root ,from_=0, to=100, width=10, textvariable=self.var)
        self.spinBox1.pack(expand = True)


class spinModuleStrB():
    ''' spinModuleNum() - Spinbox taking textvariable as <'' string value> '''
    def __init__(self, master, moduleName):
        self.root = master
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.root.grid()
        self.var = ''

        self.label1 = Label(self.root, text=self.moduleName, bg=self.root["bg"])
        self.label1.pack(expand = True)

        self.spinBox1 = Spinbox(self.root ,from_=0, to=100, width=10, textvariable=self.var)
        self.spinBox1.pack(expand = True)


class spinModuleNum():
    ''' spinModuleNum() - Spinbox taking textvariable as <numerical value> '''
    def __init__(self, master, moduleName):
        self.root = master
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.root.grid()
        self.var = 0

        self.label1 = Label(self.root, text=self.moduleName, bg=self.root["bg"])
        self.label1.pack(expand = True)

        self.spinBox1 = Spinbox(self.root ,from_=0, to=100, width=10, textvariable=self.var)
        self.spinBox1.pack(expand = True)


class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x300+500+200')
        for i in range(2): # number of columns
            self.root.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        for i in range(3): # number of rows
            self.root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.frame1 = Frame(self.root, bg='#f55')
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module1 = spinModuleStrA(self.frame1, "Spin <StringVar()> A")

        self.frame2 = Frame(self.root, bg='#faa')
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module2 = spinModuleStrA(self.frame2, "Spin <StringVar() B>")

        self.frame3 = Frame(self.root, bg='#5f5')
        self.frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module3 = spinModuleStrB(self.frame3, "Spin <''> A")

        self.frame4 = Frame(self.root, bg='#5fa')
        self.frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module4 = spinModuleStrB(self.frame4, "Spin <''> B")

        self.frame5 = Frame(self.root, bg='#55f')
        self.frame5.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module5 = spinModuleNum(self.frame5, "Spin <numerical> A")


        self.frame6 = Frame(self.root, bg='#5af')
        self.frame6.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.module6 = spinModuleNum(self.frame6, "Spin <numerical> B")

app1 = app()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is irrelevant. Passing a string or integer to the textvariable option is incorrect usage. While it will sometimes work (depending on how you define "work"), it is incorrect. The textvariable requires one of the special variable classes provided by tkinter. Without using one of those, there's no point in defining the textvariable attribute at all.

However, to answer the specific question:

**Pair A** each get a unique textvariable, so it works as expected. The underlying tcl/tk engine gets a unique string for each instance, which is why the two are independent.

**Pair B** effectively gets *no* textvariable because you specify the empty string. To the underlying tcl/tk engine an empty string in this situation is equivalent to python's `None`. If, instead of `''` you had used a non-empty string (eg: `'w00t'`), you would notice the same behavior as pair C. This is because each spinbox gets a variable with the same name, which to the underlying tcl/tk engine means they are the same textvariable and thus tied together.

**Pair C** uses a constant 0 (zero). Because it is a constant, both widgets effectively get the same textvariable because ultimately this parameter becomes the name of an tcl/tk variable. Since the name is identical for both spinboxes, they are tied together.

Comment: Haha... I guess Pair B was not suppose to work after all. I didn't test it using a non-empty double-quote string. 

From the way you put it, when passing any value which is not type `StringVar()` to Spinbox's `textvariable`, the value essentially was intepreted as the "name" or what I would describe as a `pointer` to a memory location that would become be storing the value in the associated spinbox's text entry.

This seems to be the case after I tested the script again by:
1) adding a new class definition `class spinModuleStrC()`
2) appending a few more lines of codes to `class app`

Comment: Oops... I'm so new to the way to reply by comment... It's all jumbled up...

Sorry. I wlll use the "Answer your question" option for a better layout...

Comment: yes, you are correct: tkinter uses the `str()` value of what you pass in as the name of a tcl variable. All widgets that use a textvariable with the same `str()` value are linked. Those that have unique names are not. Creating an instance of `StringVar` or `IntVar` will generate a unique name that is passed to the underlying tcl interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Haha... I guess Pair B was not suppose to work after all. I didn't test it using a non-empty double-quote string.

From the way you put it, when passing any value which is not type `StringVar()` to Spinbox's `textvariable`, the value essentially was intepreted as the "name" or what I would describe as a `pointer` to a memory location that would be storing the value in the associated spinbox's text entry.

This seems to be the case after I tested the script again by:

1. adding a new class definition `class spinModuleStrC()`
2. modifying `class spinModuleStrB()`
3. appending a few more lines of codes to `class app()`

===============================================================

1. Here are the codes for the new class `spinModuleStrC()` (Let's associate this with a new "Pair D"):

---

```
class spinModuleStrC():
    ''' spinModuleNum() - Spinbox taking textvariable as <'' string value> '''
    def __init__(self, master, moduleName):
        self.root = master
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.root.grid()

# tested this with 'r' and then with 'p' (anything different from 'r')
        self.var = 'r'   

        self.label1 = Label(self.root, text=self.moduleName, bg=self.root["bg"])
        self.label1.pack(expand = True)

        self.spinBox1 = Spinbox(self.root ,from_=0, to=100, width=10, textvariable=self.var)
    self.spinBox1.pack(expand = True)
```

2. Modification to the `class spinModuleStrB()`:
   I changed `self.var = ''` to `self.var = 'r'`
3. And the modifications to the `class app()`:

3a. modifying the `for` loop from configuring 3 rows to 4

```
    for i in range(4): # number of rows
        self.root.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
```

3b. appending new codes to the end of the `class app()`

```
    self.frame7 = Frame(self.root, bg='#5f5')
    self.frame7.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    self.module7 = spinModuleStrC(self.frame7, "Spin <'p'> A")

    self.frame8 = Frame(self.root, bg='#5fa')
    self.frame8.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
    self.module8 = spinModuleStrC(self.frame8, "Spin <'p'> B")
```

From observation, when I used `self.var = 'p'` in `spinModuleStrC()`, the spinboxes in Pair D will follow each other without intefering with the other Pairs A, B and C.

However, when I use `self.var = 'r'` in `spinModuleStrC()` - which is similar to the new `spinModuleStrB()`, the spinboxes in Pair B and Pair D will follow each other... a display of `pointer`-like behaviour in the NON-`StringVar()` type value passed to `textvariable`...

Hmmm... Perhaps this "unofficial" behaviour can be exploited

Comment: No, don't exploit it. Always use a `StringVar` or `IntVar` for a spinbox. There's simply no reason not to. Any exploitation you come up with you can get by properly using a `StringVar` or `IntVar`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Brian Oakley...

Of course anything unofficial may lead to undocumented responses. Possibly data corruption when used on older OS perhaps? Therefore not=advisable